# Verification of metric axiom 3

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

If I have a $3$ element set, say $X=\{a,b,c\}$ where $d$ is a metric on $X$ with $d(a,b)=5$ and $d(b,c)=7$, then do we have $d(a,c)\in{[0,12]}$ by the triangle inequality? since the distance is greater than or equal to $0$, but less than or equal to the sum of the other $2$ sides.

$$d(a,c)\leq d(a,b)+d(b,c),$$ $$d(a,c)\leq 5+7,$$ $$d(a,c)\leq 12.$$

Comment: You also need $d(b,c)\le d(b,a)+d(a,c)$, so $d(a,c)\ge 2$

Comment: Can you please explain to me why we also need this?

Comment: Because the triangle inequality must be true for any three points in your space. That is, what @HagenvonEitzen has written must also be true, since the distance from $b$ to $c$ must be less than or equal to the distance from $b$ to $a$ plus the distance from $a$ to $c$.

Comment: Of course, thanks to you both. :)